# Hydraulic circuit part question [Blanking Cartridge]

Tags: hydraulics, technical-drawing

There is a part in this circuit called a "Blanking Cartridge".  Its symbol looks identical to a standard capacitor in electrics. I have no idea what this part does. It is connected in parallel to a line coming out of a pressure filter and another line that next goes to tank. It is contained internally within a valve block. Does anyone know what this is? Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is commonly known as a *blanking plug* and is used to restrict or control flow in pipe circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a 2-port valve block shown below.

[image]

*Image source: [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.ie/pin/490048003200932738/).*

The main features are:

- It has two ports, 2 and 3.
- The valve is shown in the normally "open" position and there is free flow from 3 to 2.
- If the spool of the valve is pushed to the right (imagine the blocks sliding right but ports 3 and 2 remaining in position) then the valve will be "closed" and no fluid will flow from 3 to 2.

The point is that the arrow represents an open valve and the tees represent a closed valve.

Looking back at your diagram we can recognise the "closed" insert in the horizontal fluid line. The fact that it's a cartridge means that it can be added or omitted to change the function of the valve block. In this case that fluid path is always blocked by the cartridge. Another configuration might use an open or a restricted or a one-way cartridge. (A bit more context on the schematic would have been nice.)

Comment: Some are replaced with test gear on a flow bench. Used for calibration and adjustment of the device.